# AWS Java Project : HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi I'm trying to follow a tutorial on AWS to deploy a Java project. Till now I have followed the following link 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.sdlc.html
When I try to run the project locally, i.e. Test Locally , I get the below error. 
I am new to AWS so can't figure out what I am missing.

HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 53

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 53

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 53

```
50:         <div class="section grid grid5 s3">
51:             <h2>Amazon S3 Buckets:</h2>
52:             <ul>
53:             <% for (Bucket bucket : s3.listBuckets()) { %>
54:                <li> <%= bucket.getName() %> </li>
55:             <% } %>
56:             </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the line 53:

```
          <% for (Bucket bucket : s3.listBuckets()) { %>
```

is giving you an exception, most probably nullPointer because listBuckets is a null list. Please take a look on the stacktrace of your Web application (Tomcat, Jetty....) and check what is the exception and resolve it.
An 500 error is always a server error and there´s nothing related with AWS. Is a just a technical problem on your code.

Good luck.